# How many actual authors have we had posting on Literature SE?

Tags: discussion

I recall a few occasions that actual authors of works asked about here have shown up and created accounts to answer questions about their own stories. It's an awesome feeling for the site whenever that happens, so I thought we could create a list of such occasions here on meta, to be curated by the community.

How many times has this happened? Which authors have contributed to posts here about their own work?

Comment: Inspired by [a similar post on SFF meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2474/31394), and by finding one such post just now that I hadn't seen when it originally appeared.

Answer (score 3):

- [tomasz-jedrowski](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tomasz-jedrowski) https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/12725/tomasz-jedrowski
- [elizabeth-wein](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elizabeth-wein) https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/19273/elizabeth-wein
- [victor-fenech](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/victor-fenech)
  https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/16012/victor-fenech

*Please edit this answer if you're aware of more examples! It's community wiki so anyone can edit.*